# Better way to compare and set objects in lists/array (frontend angular - typescript)?

Tags: arrays, angular, list, find, compare

I know this could work, but I also believe that there is a better way to do it

So I have two lists/array with different objects, but with one attribute in common. For each element in list1, I want to find the element in list2 and set an attribute...

obj1 type is different from obj2 type

```
  for(let obj1 of this.list1) {
    for(let obj2 of this.list2) {  
        if(obj1.fieldA == obj2.fieldB) {
            obj1.fieldC = obj2.fieldD;
        }
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Map with `fieldB` as the key, and `fieldD` as the value.

Iterate `list1`, and if `fieldA` is found in the Map, set the value in `fieldC`:

```
const map = new Map(this.list2.map(({ fieldB, fieldD }) => [fieldB, fieldD]));

for(const obj1 of this.list1) {
  if(map.has(obj1.fieldA)) {
    obj1.fieldC = map.get(obj1.fieldA);
  }
}
```